# Task not creating concurrent files as stored procedure response is slow

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, task, task-parallel-library

I actually want to call my same stored procedure in concurrent tasks of C# and from that data it returns, I want to create CSV files, e.g I want to create files for all the days of a month from tasks.

The problem is that it randomly create files of few days of month.

My code is:

```
public string PopulateDateData(string strDate)
{
    string result = "";`enter code here`
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate);

    string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/CSVFile");
    string fileName = "HDPatientsStatus_" + strDate + ".csv";
    String file = folderPath + "/" + fileName;

    string SQL = " Exec [BMC_LoadPatientServices_New] '" + strDate +
        "','','','%He%','%OPD%'";
    string strErr = string.Empty;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DB.GetConnectionString());
    DataTable dtView = new DataTable();

    if (DB.Connect_SQLDataTable(ref dtView, SQL, ref con, ref strErr))
    {
        DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();

        divHtml.InnerHtml = divHtml.InnerHtml + ", Date: " + strDate;

        System.Data.DataView view = new System.Data.DataView(dtView);
        System.Data.DataTable selected = view.ToTable("Selected", false, "Row",
            "MRN", "PatientName", "ServiceName", "TimeSlot", "ServiceProvider",
            "DeliveryStatus");

        if (selected.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
         
            string date = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
            builder.Append("Dated:," + date + " ,,,,," + Environment.NewLine);
            builder.Append("Sr.No,MRN ,PatientName,ServiceName,Time Slot," +
                "Service Provider,Delivery Status" + Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (DataRow row in selected.Rows)
            {
                string Row = Convert.ToString(row[0]).Replace(",", "");
                string MRN = Convert.ToString(row[1]).Replace(",", "");
                string PatientName = Convert.ToString(row[2]).Replace(",", "");
                string ServiceName = Convert.ToString(row[3]).Replace(",", "");
                string TimeSlot = Convert.ToString(row[4]).Replace(",", "");
                string ServiceProvider = Convert.ToString(row[5]).Replace(",", "");
                string DeliveryStatus = Convert.ToString(row[6]).Replace(",", "");
                builder.Append(Row + "," + MRN + "," + PatientName + "," +
                ServiceName + "," + TimeSlot + "," + ServiceProvider + "," +
                DeliveryStatus + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            result = builder.ToString();
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(file))
                {
                    // Add some text to file    
                    Byte[] title = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(builder.ToString());
                    fs.Write(title, 0, title.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

and in the load

```
Task<string>[] taskArray = new Task<string>[5];

DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
{
    startTime = startTime.AddDays(-1);

    taskArray[i] = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew((Object strDate) =>
    {
        return PopulateDateData(strDate.ToString());
    }, startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}

Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
```

Can you all please help me out why it doesn't create all the files like here it should create files for 5 dates but it only creates for 2 dates, and rest it  returns empty data for the SP.

Why it's happening?

I am using .NET framework 4.0.

Comment: 'empty data for the SP why its happening...' You have debugged that code and checked there are no Exceptions occurring? You have an exception handler that just returns an empty string.

Comment: I dont know, if I dont run it concurrently..every thing works fine...even SP .. but with the tasks... it doesn't ..

Comment: You have some serious issues with the way you are calling the database. The conenction object needs to be in a `using`, And **do not inject data** into your query, it's **dangerous** and can cause incorrect results and leave you open to injection attacks. the way you are generating the file is also exceedingly inefficient. You don't need a stringbuilder, you can just write to the file directly using a `StreamWriter`. As to your issue: either there is no data to write (we don't know because we can't see your DB and procedure) or there's an error and it's just returning `""`

Comment: The code is full of serious problems that have nothing to do with tasks. It will fail even if it's executed sequentially. The query is created by concatenating raw strings which can lead to any kind of failures due to unnecessary formatting errors. The output is generated by writing strings without any control on how they're generated - how would `21345.67` be formatted *in Germany?* There are a lot of temporary strings generated too, which means the code will end up using multiple times the data size in RAM

Comment: As for why only two dates result in files, are you sure you aren't getting conversion errors? The code *hides* such errors with `catch {return "";}`. Perhaps `strDate` is an *invalid* date literal (string) for SQL Server? Either remove the `catch` clause completely, or log the actual error

Comment: for all , its just a test code before a better version of it, dont need to dig into code, the thing is that I only want to know why SP doesnt return the output....it returns the output when run synchronously ....yes, the connection can be the problem here..thats what I wanna know.......

Comment: the code is working fine sequentially .........